# Perché “commettere” è quasi sempre associato ad azioni negative?

Tags: word-usage

Il verbo commettere viene spesso associato ad azioni quali:

> un omicidio, un reato, un errore, un’ingiustizia, un atto impuro etc.

Secondo il Sabatini Colletti

> [Commettere](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/C/commettere.shtml):
>
> - Fare, compiere qlco., perlopiù riprovevole: commettere un omicidio
>   • sec. XIII

C’è un motivo per cui commettere viene nella maggior parte dei casi usato con accezione negativa? Esistono eccezioni nell’uso comune?

Comment: A me resulta interesante.

Comment: Perché non dovrebbe essere apprezzato? Ce ne vorrebbero di più, anzi.

Comment: L'unico esempio che ho trovato in cui non ha accezione negativa è: "Prima di commettere i lavori, dovremmo preventivare i costi totali!", dove commettere ha il significato di commissionare

Comment: E comunque quoto @DaG: ce ne fossero di domande così...

Comment: Mi riferivo a domande simili che ho fatto in passato che hanno avuto poca fortuna e qualche critica, e alla fine ho rimosso. Comunque grazie per il supporto.

Comment: Ieri un collega mi ha chiesto se avevo "committato" la versione finale di un documento. Il fatto che abbia italianizzato il verbo commit, che ha la stessa origine latina (committo) piuttosto che tradurlo con commettere, che secondo il vocabolario può anche avere il significato di "affidare", la dice lunga sul fatto che la connotazione negativa del verbo commettere è molto forte.

Comment: @CasaMich - in inglese commit (a crime, a murder etc.) ha la stessa connotazione negativa, come peraltro in francese, commetre e in spagnolo, cometer. In inglese nel gergo internet/software viene usato in senso tecnico neutro.

Comment: @Gio Grazie della precisazione, volevo solo mettere in evidenza come l'uso del verbo commettere come traduzione di commit non ha sfiorato la mente del mio collega quando parlava dell'opzione di git. In inglese esiste anche il nome commitment, con il senso di affidamento, impegno, che testimonia una non esclusione del significato positivo. In italiano invece mi sembra che l'accezione negativa ha completamente prevalso. Tuttavia devo dire che il nome commesso ha forse la stessa etimologia ma un significato positivo.

Comment: @CasaMich Beh, in italiano esiste anche *commissione* che ha una connotazione neutra (anche se un significato diverso da *commitment*).

Comment: Non conosco la risposta. Commettere è un sinonimo di "fare" ma è sicuramente usato come verbo nel campo giuridico e nelle leggi è descritto cosa è vietato, per cui "commettere" è associato genericamente a "reato" e quindi a cose cattive.

Answer (score 1):

Non sono un esperto, ma da italiano educato secondo la morale cattolica, in cui il senso di colpa ha un ruolo fondamentale, ho il sospetto che ci possa essere un'influenza di secoli di insegnamento del [sesto comandamento](http://www.vatican.va/archive/catechism_it/p3s2c2a6_it.htm), che recita

> Non commettere adulterio

o, come lo ricordo io,

> Non commettere atti impuri.

Il grave peccato descritto in queste famose espressioni potrebbe aver influito sulla connotazione del verbo.

Le eccezioni, di cui si accenna nei commenti, non mi sembrano di uso veramente comune:

- Non ho mai sentito *commettere* come traduzione dell'Inglese *commit* in ambito informatico. Ho sempre sentito utilizzare il termine inglese;
- *commessa* (*order*) e *committente* (*customer*) sono molto utilizzati, ma non il verbo *commettere* in questo contesto. Non ho mai sentito una frase che suoni come:

  > Il committente ha commesso una commessa

  Piuttosto, qui viene utilizzato *commissionare*.

Comment: È un'ipotesi interessante, ma un po' discutibile (proprio nel senso che se ne può discutere). In ambito cattolico è relativamente recente l'uso delle lingue moderne rispetto al latino (la bibbia CEI è del 1971), e ancora nel 1820 erano proibite le traduzioni italiane. Infatti, guardando la situazione con [Google Ngram](http://tinyurl.com/ydafrcfr), vediamo che “commettere un crimine” aveva una larga diffusione già nell'Ottocento, mentre quella di “commettere atti impuri” comincia a decollare negli anni Trenta... [segue]

Comment: ...l'epoca delle prime [traduzioni moderne della bibbia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traduzioni_della_Bibbia_in_italiano). D'altro canto, sembra che la frequenza della locuzione “commettere un crimine” si stia risollevando negli ultimi decenni proprio di pari passo con quella di “commettere atti impuri”. Interessante.